For a table partitioning (by date) scenario seems I have to add the date column to the PK - but doesn't this devalue the PK?
I want to partition a large table that currently has an appropriate column as the primary key.
We want to, on a regular basis, remove older rows via partition switching.
The table has a date column that I intend to use as the key for the partition function.
As I understood it, this would unavoidably mean I will have to recreate the table's primary key with a new one that uses both the original PK column plus the date column.
It strikes me that this destroys the utility of the PK.
Theoretically a duplicated value in the original single PK column would now be permitted with the new PK.
This bothers me. Is it just the way it is? No alternative? (Apart from having to add a unique constraint/index on the original PK column?)

"Table partitioning (by date) means adding the date column to the PK" this statement is false, which invalidates the rest of your post. Or do you need to use  partition switching?

Yes, I will need to do partition switching. I guess I thought it was generally required because the partition switching examples I've seen show this.

You should be specific about that in your question; it is only with switching that this is a requirement. You'll likely need to also explain why you need partition switching while not wanting that column as part of the PK. Though "is this bad design [of the RDBMS]?" Isn't really a question that is on-topic here; it's opinionated. Ask what you really need to ask, not for opinions on the product.

Thanks, I've made the edit. Now I see I should change the subject too because I did not mean to suggest a bad design of the RDBMS but of the revised table that ends up with, it seems to me, a flawed PK.

The table and indexes must be partitioned using the same (or functionally identical) partition function in order to use SWITCH or partition-level TRUNCATE. Since SQL Server requires unique partitioned indexes (including the primary key) to have the partitioning column as a key, the implication is the date partitioning column must be part of the PK to remove older data with SWITCH (or TRUNCATE).

This bothers me. Is it just the way it is? No alternative?

Apart from adding the date as a key column, the alternative is drop the PK, SWITCH, and recreate the PK as part of the purge process. This is of course not as efficient as SWITCH alone but more efficient than DELETE when a large number of rows are purged.
